# datatable.rejectchanges and RowState Modified

Tags: c#, state, datarow

### DataRow state does not reset after invoking `DataTable.RejectChanges` method

When rejecting changes with `DataTable.RejectChanges()` method the previous changed DataRow does not change it's state back to Unchanged from Modified. Workarounds I tried are:

1. Invoking `DataTable.RejectChanges()` method twice in a row like: `this.someDataSet.Tables["tableName"].RejectChanges()`, after the second method call the RowState switched from Modified to Unchanged.
2. `this.someDataSet.Tables["tableName"].RejectChanges()` and after that --> `this.someDataSet.Tables["tableName"].AcceptChanges()`

Is it so, that you always should invoke `DataTable.AcceptChanges()` after `DataTable.RejectChanges` in order accomplish the row state change back to it's original state? I've only found examples that describe the two methods separately not in conjunction.

This is what I have:

- BindingSource with a DataTable as Datasource
- Telerik radGridView for Winforms with a the BindingSource as DataSource
- Thirteen controls databound to the same BindingSource as the radGridView control

I'am making changes via databound controls not on the radGridView control. I'am using a radPageView control from Telerik to show the thirteen controls used for changes.

Thanks in advance, LH

Comment: How have you changed the row(s)? How have you checked the row-state?

Comment: The changes are made through control change event. For example a combobox SelectedIndexChanged: this._ds.Tables["tblAvvikelser"].Rows[this._bsAvvikelser.Position].SetField("Rapportdatum", this.dtpRapportdatum.Value); I check the rowstate through a method to check if there is som rows to be updated, wich I use indicate changes before I switch between different pagviews. The method iterates every row in the datatable.

Comment: You can use [`_ds.Tables["tblAvvikelser"].GetChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649.aspx).

Comment: Great, I'll do that in the future instead of iterating all the rows in the DataTable. But, what about the fact that I still got a row that has not rolled back it's status to Unchanged after DataTable.RejectChanges() method on the DataTable?